# Difference between ApexTrigger and ApexTriggerMember

Tags: trigger, rest-api, tooling-api

I am trying to understand how to manipulate triggers via the Rest API (turn them on and off). What is the difference between the "ApexTrigger" and "ApexTriggerMember" object? Does any one have any insights into updating (via PATCH method or other) these objects status?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is all in the documentation:

[ApexTriggerMember](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_apextriggermember.htm)
Represents the working copy of an Apex trigger for editing, saving or compiling in a MetadataContainer.

[ApexTrigger](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_apextrigger.htm)
Represents an Apex trigger.

Note
Although Apex classes and triggers have the Create and Update field properties, a runtime exception occurs if you try to create or update them using the API. Instead, use the Force.com Migration Tool, the Salesforce user interface, or the Force.com IDE to create or update Apex classes or triggers.